# Angular $watch Not Reacting to Directive Click Events

Tags: angularjs, scope

If i compile my element trough a linker function in a directive like this

```
    .directive('contents', function ($compile, $templateRequest,         ContentModel) {
 var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.html(scope.content.text);
      element.click(function (event) {
           scope.selected = scope.content;
           event.stopPropagation();
      });
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
 )}


    return
    scope: { selected: "=" },
    link: linker,
    controller: 'ContentsCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'contentsCtrl',
```

The directive recieves content from a main controller.
It seems like i can't get any 2 way binding of my scope.selected

When i click an object i want to set the $scope.selected object in my main controller.

in the main controller i use this for testing

```
    $scope.$watch('selected', function(){
        console.log($scope.selected);
    });
```

As you probably see i'm just a beginner at this.....

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this directive? As a rule of thumb, never use `$compile`. From the looks of it you might want to use transclusion instead

Comment: I'm building up a page from an object.
So my template is provided by a template provider.

By example a page:

        [{
            "elementType": "page",
            "properties": {
                        "class": "",
                        "style": ""
                    },
            "name": "contact",
            "inner": [
                {
                    "elementType": "row",

................

Comment: Can you put a simple plunkr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directive has some coding problems:

```
.directive('contents', function ($compile, $templateRequest,         ContentModel) {
 var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
      //Not This
      //element.html(scope.content.text);
      //Do this
      element.html(scope.contentsCtrl.content.text);

      //Not this
      //element.click(function (event) {
      //Do this
      element.on('click', function (event) {
          scope.selected = scope.contentsCtrl.content;
          //
          //Use $apply here
          //
          scope.$apply();
          //
          event.stopPropagation();
      });
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
 )}
return
scope: { selected: "=" },
link: linker,
controller: 'ContentsCtrl',
controllerAs: 'contentsCtrl',
```

### Problem #1

The directive controller is instantiated with `controllerAs: contentsCtrl`. Use `scope.contentsCtrl` to access the controller model.

### Problem #2

[AngularJS jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite) does not implement the `.click` shortcut method. Instead, use `element.on('click'`.

### Problem #3

After click events, AngularJS needs to do a digest cycle. Use `$apply` for that.

Comment: Ok, thanks.
This will take me some steps forward.

btw, the .click also works fine.
Angular itself uses a light version of JQuery but if you load JQuery before angular you have the full version....

Comment: It is best to avoid loading JQuery if not absolutely necessary.